# How to groupby with join in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

In my project I use code-first approach for Entity Framework.

I have two tables :

- `Tags` : Id, Name
- `Post` : Id, Title, Body, `List<tag>` Tags

Each post can have some tags, and some tags repeat for several posts, relation between these tables is many-to-many.

```
public class post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Title { get; set; }
    public int Body { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}

public class Tag
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}
```

I use this code but it is not okay:

```
var tags = db.posts.GroupBy(x => x.tags.Select(c => c.name)).Take(10).ToList();
```

I want get top 10 tags, but I can't do it.

I want do it by EF don't Linq

I searched on the net but can't find any similar questions.

Thanks .

Comment: show the structure of your classes and what you've tried so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
var query = (from t in ctx.Tags.Include("Posts")
            orderby t.Posts.Count() descending 
            select t).Take(10).ToList();
```

Comment: your query get all top 10 tag  . I want get top 10 tag . for example "c#" 3 times , and " mvc" use 10 times and other use first time , I want order by by useing for example "mvc" is first .

Comment: your query return "1 " for each tag . you should join by `Post` Table

Comment: You don't have to use group by. I edited the answer. Is that what you need?

Comment: I run your code . Its return All Post and order by that by Tag . I want Get TagName top 10 whiche used by post .

Comment: The code returns all tags ordered by its posts quantity. The query variable is a Tag List, not a Post List.